# How do I delay the start of a JS animation?

Tags: javascript, delay, anime.js

I was wondering if there is an easy way to delay the start of this anime.timeline animation? I have a pre-loader on my site, so I don't want this animation to trigger until the pre-loader disappears, which is after 2000 ms.

```html
<script>
anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.ml3 .letter',
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeInOutQuad",
    duration: 2250,
    delay: (el, i) => 150 * (i+1)
  }).add({
    targets: '.ml3',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 10000
  });
  </script>
```

I think this is an easy fix, but I'm still new to JS. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setTimeout() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){ 
     anime.timeline({loop: true})
       .add({
         targets: '.ml3 .letter',
         opacity: [0,1],
         easing: "easeInOutQuad",
         duration: 2250,
         delay: (el, i) => 150 * (i+1)
       }).add({
         targets: '.ml3',
         opacity: 0,
         duration: 1000,
         easing: "easeOutExpo",
         delay: 10000
       });
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

This will run your function with a 3 seconds delay.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to set timeout before animation start?

```
var animation = function(){
    setTimeout(check, 1000); 
}
animation();
```